# Why nodejs memory is not consumed for specific loop count

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I was trying to find memory leak in my code. I found out when n is, 1 < n < 257 it is showing 0KB consume, but as I put 257 it consumed memory 304KB then increase proportionally with n.

```
function somefunction()
{

    var n = 256;
    var x  ={};
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        x['some'+i] = {"abc" : ("abc@yxy.com"+i)};
    }


}

// Memory Leak
var init = process.memoryUsage();
somefunction();
var end = process.memoryUsage();
console.log("memory consumed 2nd Call : "+((end.rss-init.rss)/1024)+" KB");
```

Comment: It doesn't matters what value of n you put. Since x is local variable, memory occupied by it will be freed on the next gc run.Maybe gc cycle didn't executed by the time you recorded memoryUsage in end variable

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not leak. You cannot always expect gc to purge everything so soon.

See [Why does nodejs have incremental memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608110/why-does-nodejs-have-incremental-memory-usage)

If you want to force garbage collection, see

[How to request the Garbage Collector in node.js to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321997/how-to-request-the-garbage-collector-in-node-js-to-run)

Comment: Thank @cshu but my question was missing due 1<n<256 in stack overflow. now I updated the question. Please have a look.