# Why isn't Google App engine freeing memory using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks

So this post is a two-part question.
I am testing out the Google app engine with instance class F4 (Memory: 1024 MB and CPU 2.4GHz with automatic scaling). This is the configuration file found on App engine:

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
instance_class: F4
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
network: {}
```

My Nodejs server has normal Post and Get routes that do no heavy lifting aside from serving static files and fetching data from a MongoDB. This is the memory usage graph when using these routes:

[image: Fig 1.Graph showing memory usage as seen on Google StackDriver while fetching from these non-heavy routes]
 <sup>*Fig 1.Graph showing memory usage as seen on Google StackDriver while navigating from these non-heavy routes*</sup>

**My first question is, why does it require so much ram (around 500mb) for such small tasks?**

I am running profiling tests on my Windows 10 machine by using the Chrome Devtools Node.js Memory Profiler and its giving nowhere near these numbers, I am getting around 52MBs when taking Heap Snapshots.

My second question is about a specific route that takes an uploaded file and resizes it into 3 different images using sharp.

**Why is Memory not being freed when the resizing is complete despite working as expected on my Windows 10 machine?**

I am doing the resizing test on a ***10mb*** image which is converted into a ***buffer and then stored in memory***.
The conversion code is as follows:

```js
const resizeAndSave = (buffer, filePath, widthResize, transform) => {
  const { width, height, x, y } = transform;
  //create sharp instance
  const image = sharp(buffer);
  //prepare to upload to Cloud storage
  const file = publicBucket.file(filePath);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    image
      .metadata()
      .then(metadata => {
        //do image operations
        const img = image
          .extract({
            width: isEmpty(transform) ? metadata.width : parseInt(width),
            height: isEmpty(transform) ? metadata.height : parseInt(height),
            left: isEmpty(transform) ? 0 : parseInt(x),
            top: isEmpty(transform) ? 0 : parseInt(y)
          })
          .resize(
            metadata.width > widthResize
              ? {
                  width: widthResize || metadata.width,
                  withoutEnlargement: true
                }
              : metadata.height > widthResize
              ? {
                  height: widthResize || metadata.height,
                  withoutEnlargement: true
                }
              : {
                  width: widthResize || metadata.width,
                  withoutEnlargement: true
                }
          )
          .jpeg({
            quality: 40
          });
        //pipe to cloud storage and resolve filepath when done
        img
          .pipe(file.createWriteStream({ gzip: true }))
          .on("error", function(err) {
            reject(err);
          })
          .on("finish", function() {
            // The file upload is complete.
            resolve(filePath);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

This function is called three times in series for each image, Promise.all was not used to prevent them from running in parallel for the sake of the test:

```js
async function createAvatar(identifier, buffer, transform, done) {
  const dir = `uploads/${identifier}/avatar`;
  const imageId = nanoid_(20);
  const thumbName = `thumb_${imageId}.jpeg`;
  await resizeAndSave(buffer, `${dir}/${thumbName}`, 100, transform);
  const mediumName = `medium_${imageId}.jpeg`;
  await resizeAndSave(buffer, `${dir}/${mediumName}`, 400, transform);
  const originalName = `original_${imageId}.jpeg`;
  await resizeAndSave(buffer, `${dir}/${originalName}`, 1080, {});
  done(null, {
    thumbUrl: `https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/${dir_}/${thumbName}`,
    mediumUrl: `https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/${dir_}/${mediumName}`,
    originalUrl: `https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/${dir_}/${originalName}`
  });
  /* Promise.all([thumb])
    .then(values => {

      done(null, {
        thumbUrl: `https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/${dir_}/${thumbName}`,
        mediumUrl: `https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/${dir_}/${mediumName}`,
        originalUrl: `https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/${dir_}/${originalName}`
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {

      done(err, null);
    }); */
}
```

The heap snapshots when running the server on my Window 10 machine are :

[image: Fig 2.Heap snapshots from chrome devtools for Node.js]

<sup>*Fig 2.Heap snapshots from Chrome devtools for Node.js when navigating to the image resizing route once*</sup>

These heap snapshots clearly show that the used memory to store the 10mb image in memory and resize it is being returned to the os on My machine.

The memory usage reported on StackDriver is:
[image: Fig 3.Memory usage on Google StackDriver when image resizing route is used]
 <sup>*Fig 3.Memory usage on Google StackDriver when navigating to the image resizing route once*</sup>

This clearly shows that the memory is not being freed when the operation is done, and also is very high, starting from around 8 pm, it goes up to 800mb and never drops.

I have also tried the Stackdriver profiler but it doesn't show any high memory usage but in fact, it shows around 55mb which is close to my windows machine:

[image: Fig 4.StackDriver profiler heap shot]
 <sup>*Fig 4.StackDriver profiler heap snapshot*</sup>

So if my analysis is correct I am assuming it has something to do with the os the instances in app engine are running on? I have no clue.

**Update**: this is the latest memory usage obtained from Stackdriver after using the image processing route and not touching the app for an hour:

[image: Fig 5.Memory usage while leaving the app idle for an hour after resizing]
 <sup>*Fig 5.Memory usage while leaving the app idle for an hour after navigating to the image resize route*</sup>

**Update 2**: According to  Travis suggestion, I looked into the process while navigating to the route and found that the memory usage is slightly higher than the heap but is nowhere near what app engine is showing:
[image: Fig 6.Windows 10 Nodejs process memory]
 <sup>*Fig 6.Windows 10 process Nodejs memory while image processign is running*</sup>

**Update 3**: The number of Instances being used at the same time interval as figure 5 (while memory usage is high):
[image: Number of instances used at the same time interval as figure 5]
 <sup>*Fig 7.Number of instances used at the same time interval as figure 5*</sup>

**Update 4:** So I tried switching to instance class F1 (256 MB 600 MHz) to see what happens. The results show reduced ram usage when idle but app engine sends a warning saying to upgrade ram when I process the 10mb image. (It shows 2 instances currenltly running).
[image: F1 instance class with 256MB ram]
 <sup>*Fig 8.F1 instance class with 256MB ram when app is idle*</sup>

This leads me to think that the instances try to occuppy most of the available ram anyway.

Comment: keep in mind that heap is not the only kind of memory that programs allocate... I'd recommend looking at the memory usage of the entire process, plus any processes that it spawns, on your windows machine, not just at the heapsize. I suspect that it will then look similar to what you're seeing on app engine.

Comment: You are right about checking the process but it's still nowhere near what app engine is showing. Please see the updated question.

Comment: what image library are you using with node? normally those include binaries that spawn additional processes for image processing. my point is that you're comparing apples and oranges. understand that total memory consumption of a program is much more complex than just looking at heap size. indeed, you've noticed that heap size on both platforms is identical...

Comment: I am using sharp as I mentioned. The question is why does it require more ram on app engine than on windows 10.

Comment: Aside from running image processing, having 500mb of ram being constantly used while the app is idle seems far fetched to me.

Comment: Could you please specify the total number of instances that are running during the timestamp of the high Memory Usage incident?
I observe on the screenshots you provided, that the Stackdriver Profiler metrics display the average Memory Usage of only the Heap Memory in 7 days, whereas the GCP metrics demonstrate the Total Memory Usage (all the instances) in a specific time slot.

Comment: @ArtemisGeorgakopoulou, two instances were used and idle at the time when memory usage was high. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consequently, as a result of the aforementioned comments and your last update (Update 4), we can realize that the difference between:

- Stackdriver Profiler metrics, which display the average Memory Usage of only the Heap Memory
- and the GCP metrics, which demonstrate the Total Memory Usage (all the instances)

is an expected behavior.

One way to investigate your Node.js Application Memory Usage is to dive in the concept of the Garbage Collector.

> The job of the garbage collector (GC) is to reclaim memory occupied by unused objects (garbage).

[Here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-node-js-garbage-collection/) and [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/memory-usage-node-js/) you may find information about the Memory Management and Usage in Node.js

Additionally, Node.js launches GC when it thinks it's necessary. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608110/why-does-node-js-have-incremental-memory-usage/30614456#30614456), an idea to detect a possible memory leak would be to force the Garbage Collector manually and check if the memory is still rising. However this is not a good practice and is not suggested to use in Production, but only as a diagnostic method.